# Split table according to class - Jquery

Tags: jquery, split, html-table

I have been working on this small script which removes some unnecessary rows and columns on a table.  Each `rowspan=4` is a header for the rows below.

I am not sure how to create seperate tables from the content under each rowspan tag (retaining the header). The example/jsfiddle below would then be 3 separate tables.  This will be dynamic in that the amount of rows will vary greatly but columns will not.  Let me know if you need more info.

Let me know if I'm being unclear. I've hit a wall on this so any assistance will be very helpful.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var c1 = $("table tbody tr[rowspan='4'] td");    
  var c2 = $("table tbody tr[rowspan='4']").addClass("Header");
  var d1 = $(c1).closest("tr").next("tr");
  var d2 = $("td:nth-child(2),td:nth-child(3),td:nth-child(4)");
  var d3 = $("tr").find("td[align='right']").remove(); 
  var newTable = $(c2).nextUntil(c2).addClass("item");

  $(d1).remove();
  $(d2).remove();
  $(d3).remove(); 

  });

  <table>

  <tr rowspan="4">
    <td><b>Channel: A&amp;E</b></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Show Name</td>
    <td>Number of Episodes</td>
    <td>Duration (min)</td>
    <td>Type</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>Zoo</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>43.32</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Hoarders</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>43.32</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Total:</b></td>
        <td><b>1</b></td>
        <td colspan="2"><b>43.32 m<br>0.72 h</b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr rowspan="4">
        <td><b>Channel: Adult Swim</b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Show Name</td>
        <td>Number of Episodes</td>
        <td>Duration (min)</td>
        <td>Type</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>The Brak Show</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>35.3</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Delocated</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>201.46</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Durarara!!</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>113.89</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>113.24</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Home Movies</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>114.68</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>The Venture Bros</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>229.05</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Titan Maximum</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>23.16</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Off the Air</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>56.52</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Sealab 2021</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>33.46</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Stroker and Hoop</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>45.62</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Black Dynamite</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>113.89</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Samurai 7</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>111.23</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Sym-Bionic Titan</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>164.14</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Tenchi Muyo! GXP</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>111.09</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Total:</b></td>
        <td><b>70</b></td>
        <td colspan="2"><b>1466.73 m<br>24.45 h</b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr rowspan="4">
        <td><b>Channel: AMC</b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Show Name</td>
        <td>Number of Episodes</td>
        <td>Duration (min)</td>
        <td>Type</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>The Walking Dead</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>10.86</td>
        <td>TV Show</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Total:</b></td>
        <td><b>2</b></td>
        <td colspan="2"><b>10.86 m<br>0.18 h</b></td>
     </tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/DRCrg/2/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, i edited question.  This table should be 3 separate tables in this sample.

Comment: Still don't know what the question is.  What are you trying to do (sort of stated that)?  How is it not working?

Comment: Ah - I just don't know where to begin. Do I need to store the table rows and place into a new table? How would I go about splitting the table up into 3 separate entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dataset to group elements. i.e. `$(e).data('set', i)` in a for loop.

Then loop through all `tr` and filter those with `'set'` data key.

Finally format them into a table.

```
...
var c2 = $("table tbody tr[rowspan='4']").each(function (i, e) {
    $(e).addClass("Header").data('set', i);
});
...
var newTable = $(c2).nextUntil(c2).each(function (i, e) {
    var set = $(e).prevUntil('.Header').last().prev().data('set');
    $(e).addClass("item").data('set', set);
});
...
$(".Header").prev().remove();
var html = [];
$('#old tr').each(function (i, e) {
    if (!html[$(e).data('set')]) html[$(e).data('set')] = '';
    html[$(e).data('set')] += $(e)[0].outerHTML;
});
for (var i = 0; i < html.length; i++) {
    var result = '<br><table><tbody>' + html[i] + '</tbody></table>';
    $('body').append(result);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/indream/DRCrg/3/

Note: I've used outerHTML in the above demo, this may cause some bug in some browsers.